# C++ Splitting an array into 2 separate arrays

Tags: c++, arrays

I need to write a program that takes a given array and then splits it into two separate arrays with one array's elements being the positive elements of the main array and the other's elements being the negative elements of the main array.

After doing my best with the code, I got about a million lines of errors when trying to compile it. Is there a problem with how I am deleting the three dynamically allocated arrays? What huge error is preventing compiling?
Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


void count(int ARRAY[], int SIZE, int& NEG, int& POS);
void split(int ARRAY[], int SIZE, int& NEG_ARRAY, int NEG, int& POS_ARRAY, int POS);
void print_array(int ARRAY[], int SIZE);


int main()
{

  int SIZE(0);
  int* ARRAY;

  cout << "Enter number of elements: ";
  cin >> SIZE ;

  ARRAY = new int[SIZE];
  int x(0);
  int numEle(0);

  cout << "Enter list: " << endl;

  while (numEle < SIZE)
  {
      ARRAY[numEle] = x;
      numEle++;
      cin >> x;
  }

  int POS(0), NEG(0);
  count(ARRAY, SIZE, NEG, POS);

  int* NEG_ARRAY;
  NEG_ARRAY = new int[NEG];

  int* POS_ARRAY;
  POS_ARRAY = new int[POS];


  split(ARRAY, SIZE, NEG_ARRAY, NEG, POS_ARRAY, POS);

  cout << "Negative elements: " << endl;
  cout << print_array(NEG_ARRAY, NEG) << endl;

  cout << "Non-negative elements: " << endl;
  cout << print_array(POS_ARRAY, POS) << endl;


  delete [] ARRAY;
  delete [] NEG_ARRAY;
  delete [] POS_ARRAY;

  return 0;
}

void count(int ARRAY[], int SIZE, int& NEG, int& POS)
{
    for (int x=0; x < SIZE; x++)
    {
        if (ARRAY[x] >= 0)
    {
        POS = POS + 1;
    }
        if (ARRAY[x] < 0)
    {
        NEG = NEG + 1;
    }
    }
}

void split(int ARRAY[], int SIZE, int& NEG_ARRAY, int NEG, int& POS_ARRAY, int POS)
{
    NEG = POS = 0;
    for (int x = 0; x < SIZE; x++)
    {
        if (ARRAY[x] < 0)
    {
            NEG_ARRAY[NEG++] = ARRAY[x];
        }
        else
        {
            POS_ARRAY[POS++] = ARRAY[x];
        }
    }
}

void print_array(int ARRAY[], int SIZE)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        cout << ARRAY[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

The code is supposed to read in the array and display a new negative and a new positive array.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please include the errors into your question.

Comment: What is the *first* error you get? Did you try to debug? Did you try to run your code before it has been completed?

Comment: There are literally too many to include. I tested the code up to and including the "void count(int ARRAY[], int SIZE, int&NEG, int&POS);" function. The first few errors are: "line49:invalid initialization of reference type 'int&' from expression of type 'int*'.   line13: error in passing argument 3 of 'void split(int*, int,int&, int, int&, int)'  and line52: no match for 'operator<<' in 'std::cout << print_array(NEG_ARRAY, NEG)'.    After that I see a lot of '<_CharT, _Traits>' in the errors if that helps

Comment: Why are you setting `NEG` and `POS` to zero in your split function?  These don't even need to be passed into `split`.  If we assume that `NEG_ARRAY` and `POS_ARRAY` are the correct size, you might as well use local variables to keep track of the current place in these arrays.  If we don't assume this, what you use the size variables for still doesn't make sense - it would make more sense to use them, in this case, to make sure you are within the valid indices.

Comment: Shouldn't you be reading the value before storing it? so cin>>x; before ARRAY[numEle] = x, otherwise you'll lose the first value and you'll be "off by one".

Comment: ^^^ Also, that.  And also, just fyi, variables in all caps generally mean that they are `#define`d constants.

Comment: The memory management seems correct, but without seeing your errors, we can't even be sure that they have to do with memory management.  At least provide some information...

Comment: Would either of those issues be giving me this many errors? Those seem to simple for the multitude of errors I'm getting. I would think it has to be something major that is incorrect.

Comment: function print_array(POS_ARRAY, POS) is returning void. y are you calling it from cout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a bunch of errors in your code. The worst one is passing the arrays by references in the declaration and definition of the `split` function. Change both to `void split(int ARRAY[], int SIZE, int *NEG_ARRAY, int NEG, int *POS_ARRAY, int POS);`, and most of the errors will be gone.

The rest is from the two lines in which you print the array in your `main`:

```
cout<<print_array(NEG_ARRAY, NEG) <<endl;
```

You don't want to print the function, you want to **use** the function to print inside it (which you do correctly). You need to change the calls to simply:

```
print_array(NEG_ARRAY, NEG);
```

And that'll make your code compile.

Hovewer there's one more error, which will make the whole app work in an improper way. In the place you input the values, you need to get the input from `cin` **before** inputting it in the array. Like this:

```
while(numEle<SIZE) {
  cin>>x;
  ARRAY[numEle] = x ;
  numEle++;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for all of your help. Explanations were very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You have the following bugs:

```
void split(int ARRAY[], int SIZE, int&NEG_ARRAY, int NEG, int&POS_ARRAY, int POS);
```

change to :

```
void split(int ARRAY[], int SIZE, int*NEG_ARRAY, int NEG, int*POS_ARRAY, int POS);
```

also the :

```
void split(int ARRAY[], int SIZE, int&NEG_ARRAY, int NEG, int&POS_ARRAY, int POS){..}
```

change to :

```
void split(int ARRAY[], int SIZE, int*NEG_ARRAY, int NEG, int*POS_ARRAY, int POS){..}
```

and

```
cout<<print_array(NEG_ARRAY, NEG) <<endl
cout<<print_array(NEG_ARRAY, POS) <<endl;
```

to :

```
print_array(NEG_ARRAY, NEG);
print_array(NEG_ARRAY, POS);
```

After fixed these bugs, it can compile and run well.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, using a `std::vector` is almost always nicer than using dynamically allocated C arrays. You don't get the horrible mixture of pointers and square bracket array access, and you don't need to pass round extra size variables.

Secondly, the standard library has some nice algorithms to help do what you want to do. Let's assume that you write the given numbers into a vector called `vec`. You can then use `std::partition` to move all the elements less than zero to the first half of the vector, and all the elements greater than or equal to zero to the second half, like so:

```
inline bool less_than_zero(int a)
{
    return a < 0;
}

std::vector<int>::iterator midpoint = std::partition(vec.begin(),
                                                     vec.end(),
                                                     less_than_zero);
```

(There are other ways of specifying the predicate, but a simple function definition like this is easiest for demonstration purposes.)

The returned iterator points to the first item in the vector which is non-negative. So now you can easily copy the values into two new vectors:

```
std::vector<int> negative(vec.begin(), midpoint);
std::vector<int> positive(midpoint, vec.end());
```

And that's it!